# Is there a way to check if an object is currently colliding with anything?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I need to test from another Script on a different GameObject, whether a particular GameObject is colliding with anything (in particular using trigger).

So, for my purpose, I don't need OnCollisionEnter/OnTriggerEnter events, but I need something like this:

```
if ( myObject.isOnCollision ) 
   do something
```

How can I do this?

Comment: For clarification: So you have an object with a trigger-collider, and you want to know if a specific other game object (which you already have in a variable) is currently inside the trigger-collider of your current game object?

Comment: You can send an event when a collision happens to another object, or just boolean variable with a getter method and test again it in update.

Comment: I've edited your question to try to clarify, since I saw it was getting some close votes for being unclear. Please feel free to revert or improve the edits if I've misunderstood your aim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a trigger collider to keep track of whether *anything* is touching it, you can attach a script to it like so:

```
public class Sensor : MonoBehaviour {
    int _overlaps;

    public bool isOverlapping {
        get {
            return _overlaps > 0;
        }
    }

    // Count how many colliders are overlapping this trigger.
    // If desired, you can filter here by tag, attached components, etc.
    // so that only certain collisions count. Physics layers help too.
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        _overlaps++;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
        _overlaps--;
    }
}
```

Now another script with a reference to `public Sensor mySensor;` can query `if(sensor.isOverlapping) {...}` to change behaviour when something is inside this sensor trigger.

Or you can use the various Physics.OverlapBox/OverlapSphere/etc. methods to query a shape of space for collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tags or layers I guess to make sure it is the right object that is colliding. So I believe (if I understood correctly your problem) that you need in fact OnCollisionEnter/OnTriggerEnter.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision){ 
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "TheOtherObjectTag"){
      Debug.Log("Collision using tag");
    }
    if (collision.gameObject.layer == 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("TheOtherObjectLayer")){
      Debug.Log("Collision using layer");
    }
    if (GameObject.ReferenceEquals(collision.gameObject,myOtherGameObject)){
      Debug.Log("Collision using an object reference");
    }
}
```

I didn't try the code but I think the syntax is OK. Tell me if this is not what  you need, and please explain further if it is not.

Comment: When you aren't sure you understood the question correctly then it is usually better to post a comment and ask for clarification than to guess what could be meant and post an answer which could be misleading.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure about my code it works and using it.

first you need a void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) unity builtin function to use enter collider or for exit collider functions 
create a tag and use exact name

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Mytag")
    {
        GameObject explosion = Instantiate(Resources.Load("FlareMobile", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
        explosion.transform.position = transform.position;
        Destroy(explosion, 2);
        explosionAud.Play();
        boxend();

        Debug.Log("fireeeee");
        //   Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this help the user check, from an outside script, whether `myObject` is colliding with something?